# how to make dropdown using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I tried to write the code of this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9qTt.png), but I faced some difficulties.i want to make dropdown using css as shown in the image.For more help i added orignal website link http://uos.edu.pk/

MY SAMPLE OF CODE IS HERE

```
  <style>
  select{
   background-color:#183287;
   color:white;
   border:none;
  }
   div.divofmenu{
    height:40px;
   width:100%;
   border:0px solid white;
   float:left;
   border-bottom:2px solid white;
   background-color:#183287;
  }
 ul.menu
 {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-left:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  padding:0;
  margin-top:0px;
  border-color:black;
  border-width:3px;

  }
  ul.menu li
  {
  margin-top:0px;

  float:left;
  }


  ul.menu li a{
   text-decoration:none;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-left:3;
   color:white;
   background-color:#183287;
  font-size:90%;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
   border-left:0.5px solid black;



}
</style>

<body>
<div class="divofmenu">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="about"><a style="border:0px white"href="#">
<select class="select"><option>About us</option></select>
</a>
</li>
<li class="acad"><a href="#">
 <select class="select"><option>Acadmics</option></select>
 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">
<select class="select"><option>campus</option></select>
</a></li>
<li><a href="#">
<select class="select"><option>Faculties</option></select>
</a></li>
<li><a href="#">
<select class="select"><option>Directorate</option></select>
</a></li>
<li><a href="#">
<select class="select"><option>Admisions</option></select>
</a></li>
<li><a href="#">
<s
```

Comment: What kind of difficulties are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that like this?

```css
.dropdown{
        background-color:#183287;
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 .dropdown-content{
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     left: -200%;
     background-color:#183287;
     min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     padding: 12px 16px;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: left;
 }

 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
     display: block;
 }

    .col-1{
      float: left; 
    }
    .col-2{
      float: right; 
    }

   div.divofmenu{
    height:40px;
   width:100%;
   border:0px solid white;
   float:left;
   border-bottom:2px solid white;
   background-color:#183287;
  }
 ul.menu
 {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-left:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  padding:0;
  margin-top:0px;
  border-color:black;
  border-width:3px;

  }
  ul.menu li
  {
  margin-top:0px;

  float:left;
  }


  ul.menu li a{
   text-decoration:none;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-left:3;
   color:white;
   background-color:#183287;
  font-size:90%;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
   border-left:0.5px solid black;



}
```

```html
<div class="divofmenu">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="about"><a style="border:0px white"href="#">
<div class="dropdown">
     About Us
 <div class="dropdown-content">
   <div class="col-1">
              Column 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              Column 2
            </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes rmondesilva i want this and this is the correct answer i want

Comment: thanx for helping me